# Amending a commit with GitHub Desktop

Tags: github, github-desktop

I need to amend last commit. I want to use GitHub Desktop.
I read instructions in [this GitHub docs page](https://docs.github.com/en/desktop/contributing-and-collaborating-using-github-desktop/managing-commits/amending-a-commit).  But when I try to do - this is as described in the instructions, there is no such item in the menu:

[image: image of popup menu from GitHub Desktop]

Comment: Try to avoid just posting images as the key parts of questions; see [ask]. If you do need to use an image (this may be the case here), consider using an inline image and/or putting in a proper description.

Comment: Have you updated to the latest version of GitHub Desktop?

Comment: @The Otterlord I update GitHub Desktop to the latest version.

Comment: @torek I can't add inline image

Comment: @Orest: of course you can. Include a leading exclamation point. See [this meta stack exchange Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310922/641754). (See also [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75491/641754).)

Comment: @torek 
I have too low a rating

Comment: I think you can still edit your own postings, but I did this one for you. (As for GitHub Desktop: I don't use it myself, so I have no idea what the actual problem in GitHub Desktop is.)